# Determine if a document library is a sharepoint library

Tags: document-library, content-type, event-handlers

I'm adding some content types to every standard-document library which is created over the "List Added"-EventReceiver. 
When a web is created the are some new doclibs for example in a team site there is are "shared documents" and "Site Assets".

My problem is that I only want to add the content types to the standard doclibs like "shared documents" in my example above but not in "Site Assets". How can I determine if a doclib is a standard doclib and not a sharepoint-specific doclib?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check the [TemplateFeatureId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.templatefeatureid.aspx) property of the SPList object, to see which feature the list template belongs to. The AssetLibrary feature has ID={4BCCCD62-DCAF-46dc-A7D4-E38277EF33F4} .

In a Team Site on the other hand the "Site Assets" is created as a document library in code, using the same template feature as "Shared Documents" (ID={00bfea71-e717-4e80-aa17-d0c71b360101}). One thing that distinguishes the Site Assets lib though is that it has the [IsAssetsLibrary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.issiteassetslibrary.aspx) property set to true. But that can only be used to identify if it is a Site Assets library or not.

Some clever combination of these should help you out.